# Unlock code to close a lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I want someone to enter an 'unlock code' on a lightbox to close that lightbox.

Using the lightbox script that I use, to close the lightbox I could normally use the code:

```
onclick = "close()"
```

Or adding to an element: `class = "close"`

Instead I'd like it to close when the right unlock code is chosen. Any thoughts on how best to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, depending if you want a dynamic or static code there will be different approaches.

If you want a dynamic code, you will need a javascript-function creating a code and appending it to an element when lightbox is triggered. Then compare the value of a input field to that javascript variable created from this function. If they do compare, fire the close(); function.

If you just want a static code you would simply go about with:

```
$("#id_of_textbox").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        if( $(this).val() == 'close' ) {
            close();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that. So your first suggestion looks a bit like the code here: [link] http://www.htmlfreecodes.com/Put_password_on_your_website_to_protect_your_pages--view--.htm[/link]

If that's right, how would I change going to a 'location' to action the close()?

Comment: I'm relatively new to this... If using your static code would the full code look like this, with the unlock code in this this case being 'close'? 
<code>
<input type="text" name="unlock" value="Unlock Code" id="unlock" size="16" maxlength="16" /> 

$("unlock").keyup(function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        if( $(this).val() == 'close' ) {
            close();
        }
    }
});</code>

Comment: Sorry for my lack of response as I am at work at the moment. But yes, your last comment captures my intentions of a static unlock code. If they enter "close" to the text-field and hit the enter key, the function close(); will be called, which I guess terminates the lightbox-window.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.

If anyone has a suggestion as to how to change the linked code [link]www.htmlfreecodes.com/Put_password_on_your_website_to_protect_your_pages--view--.htm%5B/link%5D[/link] I posted here to make it work I'd be really grateful too as that looks like a good approach.

Comment: That link didn't work - heres the right one: [link]http://www.htmlfreecodes.com/Put_password_on_your_website_to_protect_your_pages.htm [/link]

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. Here's how I solved it:

```
    <script language="javascript">
function password(form) { 
if (form.pass.value=="password") {              
close(); 
} else {
alert("Invalid unlock code")
}
}
</script>

<center>
<form name="login">Unlock code:  <input name="pass"
type="password">   <input type="button" value="Submit"
onClick="password(this.form)">
</script>`
```

You could use the same code adapted to use a password to take you to a website:

```
<script language="javascript">
function password(form) { 
if (form.pass.value=="password") {              
location="http://www.bbc.com" 
} else {
alert("Invalid unlock code")
}
}
</script>

<center>
<form name="login">Unlock code:  <input name="pass"
type="password">   <input type="button" value="Submit"
onClick="password(this.form)">
```